# Dynamic Pivot table failing - can't figure out how to make this work

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I'm trying to create a dynamic pivot table with a PERIOD column as a header - the period is literally the year concatenated with the month e.g. 201608

This one keeps tripping over, I've tried a lot of the solutions I have found online and have tried to rearrange it completely several times.

Can anyone help me? The query itself is very simple.

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR
DECLARE @PERIOD VARCHAR = '201608'
DECLARE @col1 AS VARCHAR


SELECT @col1 = ISNULL(@col1, 0) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [PERIOD] AS col1 
FROM [DimDate] WHERE LEFT([PERIOD], 4) = LEFT(@PERIOD, 4)) AS [TEST]


SET @query = 
'SELECT * 
    FROM
    (SELECT 1 as NGroup, [PERIOD], MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL, Amount 
          from [NewMember]) AS s
    PIVOT
    (COUNT(Amount) FOR [PERIOD] IN (' + @col1 + ')) AS pvt'
PRINT @query
EXEC @query
```

Comment: Try `declare xxx NVARCHAR(MAX)` when declaring the string variables

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have helped move it forward in some way, but the following error is occurring now..  SELECT * 
 FROM
 (SELECT 1 as NGroup, [PERIOD], MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL, Amount 
              from [NewMember]) AS s
  PIVOT
  (COUNT(Amount) FOR [PERIOD] IN (0)) AS pvt
Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 17
The name 'SELECT * 
 FROM
 (SELECT 1 as NGroup, [PERIOD], MEMBERSHIP_LEVEL, Amount 
              from [NewMember]) AS s
  PIVOT
  (COUNT(Amount) FOR [PERIOD] IN (0)) AS pvt' is not a valid identifier. Any ideas? Thanks for your help so far :-)

Comment: Have you tried removing the variable and using an actual value? Do you still get the same error? Also could you paste the PRINT @query output into your question? It might also be helpful if you update your original question with your new syntax!

Comment: Thank you, I've got this working now perfectly! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Great! @Lucy, Perhaps put your solution in the answer section to help other folk with similar problem?